# how to specify the user error message in getMessage in laravel

Tags: laravel

how can I specify the user error message for the getMessage in throw function?

```
 catch(Exception $e){
      \Session::flash('error', 'Unable to process request.Error:'.json_encode($e->getMessage(), true));
  }
```

Comment: You can do that only for the exceptions you are throwing by yourself: `throw new Exception('This is your custom message');`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to encode

```php
catch(Exception $e){
      \Session::flash('error', 'Unable to process request.Error:'.$e->getMessage());
  }
```